# Davinci Resolve 15 - color correction of whole tracks

Tags: davinci-resolve, color-correction, tracks

I have a video project which I have cut and edited and now I want to adjust color (temperature) of one track that contains clips from one camera (2nd track contains clips from 2nd camera), I know it is possible to adjust individual clips, but I want to do it for the whole track because it is the same camera with the same settings. Or do I have to adjust individual clips manualy?

I bet the functionality must be somewhere and I just can't find it.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A couple of ways you can do this.  My faforite is groups.  In the color page, do this:

1. Shift click all of the clips you want to color correct at the same time.  You can limit the clips shown on the color page to a single track by disabling the video tracks on either the color page or the edit page.
2. Right-click on any of the now selected clips to bring up a contextual menu.
3. Choose "Add into a new group" from the menu.
4. Click the disclosure triangle next to the word "Clip" above the node viewer.
5. Select either "group pre-clip" or "group post-clip" from the dropdown.

You'll now notice green chain link icons across all of the clips you have grouped together.  When you grade one, it will grade all of the other ones that are linked.  Additionally, If you switch the node viewer back to "clip," you can stack additional corrections on your group corrections.  The order of operations depends on whether you used "pre" or "post" and you can always do both.

I might, for example, do a basic first pass in group-pre, matching all of the cameras' white balance, exposure, and look.  Then, once everything matches, move clip-by clip in "clip" view, making individual adjustments on a case-by-case basis.  Then, I might use "group-post" if I notice all of the grouped cameras still need a group-based adjustment, perhaps to un-distort a lens, for example.  Finally, you can use "Timeline" view in the node viewer to apply an overall grade to the whole timeline, which is useful for "legalizing" the whole program; making sure the waveform and vector scopes stay within range for the whole show.

The group method is good, because while you can restrict a group correction to a particular track, or a particular camera, you don't have to, and a clip can belong to multiple groups.  So, for example, if I'm using two different cameras, the cameras have different looks AND interchangeable lenses; if the cam-ops swap lenses during the shoot, I can have a group for cameras, and a group for lenses.  I can then match the color of the cameras to each other in the camera group, then match the distortion in the lens group, and it doesn't matter that the cam-ops swapped lenses.

Another, perhaps less complicated method is to:

1. Grade your clip.
2. Switch to the edit page.
3. Copy your clip
4. Select all of the clips that you want to bestow the first clip's correction upon.
5. Paste Attributes (alt/option-v).  Under the Video section, make sure "Color Correction" is checked, and unless you want to affect other elements of the target clips, make sure all of the other boxes are unchecked.

Answer (score 1):

Just color correct one clip according to your specifications and then select that clip first and then all other which you want to have the same color correction. To select the other clips you can do ctrl + click. This way all the clips which you selected, will have the same color correction as of the first clip. I saw this in some YouTube video.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have tested it and it does not work, but I figured it out thanks to you. First, I have to correct one clip, then select all clips I want to adjust, after that select the one I have corrected (it has to be the last one in selection), right click and select Apply Grade.